# UEFI/BIOS password not working anymore after BIOS update

Tags: boot, bios, dell-inspiron

I had a BIOS password set up in the past and it allways worked fine up untill now. The BIOS for my computer ( Dell Inspiron3505(the keyboard is the latin american one))) got updated ( I updated it today but update was available days ago) and the password (the one I had set up isn't working anymore and I know I am writing it correctly because I have to use it every day lots of times after the computer is suspended for a while , so I suppose it (BIOS) isn't recognising the keyboard correctly (the one that comes with the laptop)). The following is the link to the latest version of the BIOS for my computer
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=60ck7&lwp=rt

How can I fix this? I can't seem to flash bios to older version (BIOS is InsydeH2O)

Comment: Have you tried a USB keyboard? BTW, if there are characters with diacritics, this poses additional problems.

Comment: I have, it didn't work. I'm still trying to figure it out. @DrMoishePippik

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to fix without clearing password: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-3505-laptop/inspiron-3505-service-manual/clearing-bios-system-setup-and-system-passwords?guid=guid-5941e06e-abcb-4468-ace5-d51ef6aaa083&lang=en-us .

Comment: I called and they said the the technical support service period is over. I don't know how to renew it if possible at all. I'm considering trying to recover the BIOS through the BIOS recovery mechanism, but I don't know I'm scared it will cause even more trouble if a fix was to come later on.

Comment: I was considering two options: either the password got overwritten or something like that or the keyboard isn't correctly recognised by the BIOS program... I don't know if either are possible, but the fact is that the password I used in the past isn't working anymore

Comment: As mentioned, if there are non-ANSI letters, e.g., Å, ç, or ü, it can cause difficulties with BIOS password. After an experiment I made using a Cyrillic keyboard layout, I found my local *OS* password could not be entered! (Luckily, the drive was not encrypted, so the password could be removed easily.)

Comment: Honestly, I believe what is causing trouble is a space(bar) character, the rest of the characters in the password are just numbers. The BIOS accepts almost every character in my keyboard (though I am not exactly sure which are being entered because I can't see through the pass. censoring  ***) the computer has a numeric keypad and once I block num I can input those just fine. That's why I believe the only problem (supposing the BIOS isn't interpreting the kboard correctly and that the pass. wasn't overwritten) is the space character